# php preg_match positive lookahead not working as expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$regex  = '/(?<=(total: ))(\$\d+\.\d+)/';
$search = '$1.25 cart total: $24.99 $55.50';

preg_match($regex, $search, $price);
```

I would like to extract '$24.99' from the string above.

When I print_r the $price array, it is blank. According to this tool: http://regexr.com?2vfm9 my regex should be working correctly. When I run the code using only the "(\$\d+.\d+)" part of regex, the array returns all of the prices... so I know that part is working.

Am I implementing the positive lookahead incorrectly? Any other thoughts?

---

UPDATE:
I think I might have found the problem:

The text that I am parsing has a "& nbsp;" after the colon. It wasn't showing when I displayed the raw text to myself, but was interfering with the regex. I'll update to confirm.

Comment: I have tried your code and it "works" ! `print_r($price);` gives me `Array ( [0] => $24.99 [1] => total: [2] => $24.99 )`

Comment: `$price` is not blank, http://codepad.viper-7.com/YQxEDN

Comment: for me local in my Work station work fine. I don't realy know what's wrong with that. But, I have notice in another host, that I use to test some PHP that not all of my regex works. So, try to find out if there is any option for regex in PHP

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I made a simpler example of my problem to post on here... and my example worked. I'll try to figure out what my actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with `&nbsp;` you could use:

```
$regex  = '/(?<=(total:))[^$]+(\$\d+\.\d+)/';
$search = '$1.25 cart total:&nbsp;$24.99 $55.50';

preg_match($regex, $search, $price);
print_r($price);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => &nbsp;$24.99
    [1] => total:
    [2] => $24.99
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need capturing parentheses around `total:`, in fact they are even detrimental in this case. They capture.

Try without them.

And by the way, what you are using here is a positive lookbehind, not lookahead, and I don't see why you use one at all?

Comment: The regexr tool calls the ?<= a 'positive lookahead'. But I'm not claiming that I am right.

Comment: You are right that I can live without the capturing parentheses. If you can think of a regex that can only capture the $24.99 string without using lookaheads or lookbehinds, I am all ears.

Comment: Just don't use one: `'/total: (\\$\\d+.\\d+)/'`. That should work fine.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that now the word "total" is being matched too. I suppose I can scrub it out with a second regex... I was hoping to save a step. Thanks.

Comment: But hey, you have capturing parentheses, don't you? Just take what is in the group, not the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `\` are not escaped:

```
$regex  = '/(?<=(total: ))(\\$\\d+\\.\\d+)/';
```

Comment: The escaping didn't make a difference. My mini sample still works with the escaping, but my real problem does not. Thanks for the suggestion.